# SSIS Convert english BlobColumn to String ending up with Chinese characters

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005, ssis

I am transferring data from MS SQL to MYSQL. The transfer works, but having trouble with BlobColumn. I am achieving the transfer using a script component, and coding the insert statement. I have several blob columns that are 'text' columns in MySQL. I am converting like this:

```
Replace(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Row.link_desc.GetBlobData(0, Convert.ToInt32(Row.link_desc.Length))), "'","\'")
```

It transfers the contents, but they are in Chinese characters after the transfer. I assume this has something to do with the Encoding, but not sure what.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the data coming in may be ASCII and your encoding is Unicode. Try:

```
Replace(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Row.link_desc.GetBlobData(0, Convert.ToInt32(Row.link_desc.Length))), "'","\'")
```